# simple conditional probability question

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Let's say I have two variables $A$ and $B$ and I want to write the probability that $A=2$ conditional on $B=1$, which of the two ways would be correct:

$$P(A=2 | B=1) $$

or

$$ P(A=2 \cap B=1) $$

Comment: It's the first. The second is the probably that $A=2$ AND $B=1$.

Comment: Okay maybe I am misunderstand conditional probability then, isnt conditional probability that A=2 AND B=1?

Comment: That's the probability that $A=2$ *if* you know $B=1$.

Comment: So in the above example, assuming independence $P(A=2|B=1)$ is $P(A=2)$ and $P(A=2 \cap B=1)$ is $P(A) \cdot P(B)$

Comment: Yes, in general $P(A \cap B)=P(A \;|\; B)P(B)$. Wikipedia has a good reference [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability).

Comment: By definition a "process" is a set of random variables *indexed by a set of times or locations.* Because you use no indexing and equate these "processes" with numbers, it doesn't appear that you are asking about processes at all.  What, then, are you really asking about??

Comment: The only way your question could make sense would be if time has been fixed.  The analogy to dice tossing makes no sense at all.

Comment: Can you please tag this as self-study (and read the self-study tag wiki?

Answer (score 2):

The [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) $P(A=2 \:|\: B=1)$ is the probability that $A=2$ given that $B=1$.

The [joint probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution) $P(A=2 \cap B=1)$ is the probability that $A=2$ and $B=1$.

In general, these two expressions are related by
$$P(A=2 \cap B=1) = P(A=2 \:|\: B=1)P(B=1).$$